# ¿Cómo puedo utilizar el metodo split en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, split

Eestoy intentando separar la parte inicial de una dirección de correo electrónico, para esto estoy usando el metodo split. Mi separador debería ser el simbolo "@".

Adjunto mi codigo:

```js
 const dividirCadena = (cadenaADividir, separador) => {
    let arrayDeCadenas = cadenaADividir.split(separador);

 for (let i = 0; i < arrayDeCadenas.length; i++) {
      console.log(arrayDeCadenas[i] + " / ");
    }
   
 const cadenaVerso ="prueba@uno.com";
 const arroba = "@";

     dividirCadena(cadenaVerso, arroba);
```

Comment: Con esa edición la pregunta ya está respondida sola.

Comment: @Mateo no, tiene un error de sintaxis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya casi lo tenías, solo faltaría cerrar las llaves de tu función:

```js
const dividirCadena = (cadenaADividir, separador) => {
  let arrayDeCadenas = cadenaADividir.split(separador);

  for (let i = 0; i < arrayDeCadenas.length; i++) {
    console.log(arrayDeCadenas[i]);
  }
};
const cadenaVerso = 'prueba@uno.com';
const arroba = '@';

dividirCadena(cadenaVerso, arroba);
```

Answer (score 2):

Lo estas haciendo bien, solo que no estas guardando el `split` en ningun lugar.

La manera correcta de hacer lo que quieres hacer seria la siguiente:

```js
const dividirEmail = (email, separador) => {
    return email.split(separador);
}

const email = "test@test.com";
const separador = "@";

const emailSeparado = dividirEmail(email, separador);
const inicioEmail = emailSeparado[0];
const finalEmail = emailSeparado[1];

console.log("Inicio del email:", inicioEmail);
console.log("Dominio del email:", finalEmail);
```

En este código lo que hacemos es retornar el primer elemento del `split`, ya que el método `split` lo que hace es separar el string en un array, evitando el separador. Solo queremos la parte inicial asé que con el primer elemento nos sirve. El primer elemento será guardado en una constante `inicioEmail`.

Para mas información sobre los metodos de string, la documentación de mozilla ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)) contiene todo sobre sus metodos.

Comment: mmmm tan solo le faltaba una llave, no era darle otro ejercicio :/...

Comment: @Cris223511.dev Cuando yo leí la pregunta, no tenía el bucle xd

Comment: @Cris223511.dev pasa que alguien editó antes la pregunta y añadió el bucle. [Historial de revisiones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/575717/revisions)